# I have problem in .htaccess in my localhost not redirecting correctly

Tags: php

My .htaccess file contains:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule projects$ projects.php
RewriteRule projects/$ projects.php
RewriteRule projects/page/([^/]*)$ projects.php?page=$1
RewriteRule projects/page/([^/]*)/$ projects.php?page=$1
RewriteRule projects/company/([^/]*)/$ projects.php?companyid=$1
RewriteRule projects/company/([^/]*)$ projects.php?companyid=$1
RewriteRule projects/([^/]*)$ projects.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It was working fine, but suddenly this section is not working in my website.

This should redirect to "projects.php?companyid=$firstvariable",
but actually, I don't know why.

I tried restarting my PC and deleting temp and restarting WAMP.

Comment: Where does it actually redirect to, if it doesn't redirect to where you intended?  That might point at what's wrong.

Comment: http://localhost/alwathiq/projects/company/damac
this is the URL which should redirect to page projects.php?companyid=damac 
and it only redirect to projects.php without GET 
and i don't know how to fix that

Comment: It sounds like you have another `RewriteRule` in your `.htaccess` file that is rewriting the URL first, without the query string.  Could you include your entire `.htaccess` file for us to see?

Comment: `Options +FollowSymlinks 

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule projects$ projects.php
RewriteRule projects/$ projects.php

RewriteRule projects/page/([^/]*)$ projects.php?page=$1
RewriteRule projects/page/([^/]*)/$ projects.php?page=$1

RewriteRule projects/company/([^/]*)/$ projects.php?companyid=$1
RewriteRule projects/company/([^/]*)$ projects.php?companyid=$1

RewriteRule projects/([^/]*)$ projects.php?id=$1 [L] `

this is the entire file 
but i tried to remove all lines and let the specific line but same result

Comment: As you are using relative URLs in your `RewriteRule`s, you may need to specify `RewriteBase` as well.  Try putting `RewriteBase "/alwathiq/"` on its own line after the `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: `Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/alwathiq/"
RewriteRule projects/([^/]*)$ projects.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule projects/company/([^/]*)/$ projects.php?companyid=$1
RewriteRule projects/company/([^/]*)$ projects.php?companyid=$1
RewriteRule projects/page/([^/]*)$ projects.php?page=$1
RewriteRule projects/page/([^/]*)/$ projects.php?page=$1
RewriteRule projects$ projects.php
RewriteRule projects/$ projects.php`

i put it but same result.
it only redirect me to projects.php without GET

Comment: What directory did you put this `.htaccess` file in?  If it's in the docroot, then you'll need to modify your `RewriteRule`s ... otherwise, your `.htaccess` file should be placed in the `alwathiq` subfolder.

Comment: actually it's in alwathiq folder
but i tried something that may help , i have 2 version of wamp i tried elder one and it works fine .
so i think it's cash problem in Apache maybe .

Comment: Probably not caching, but maybe there's another `.htaccess` file in a parent directory that is conflicting/being processed first.

Comment: there is no files in parent directories and i tried to uninstall/install but same problem

Comment: Sorry, I'm all out of ideas - I'd need remote access to the computer in question to poke around to be able to solve this problem, at this point.

Comment: ok email me on zozodoth@gmail.com and i can give u team-viewer access

Answer (score 0):

After some interactive troubleshooting with OP, it appears that WAMP's Apache/PHP will execute a PHP file that matches the directory portion of the URL path if it exists, before applying the `.htaccess` `RewriteRule`s.

In other words, if you have a file named `Abc.php`, and you request `/Abc/def`, WAMP's Apache/PHP will just execute `Abc.php` and not consult the `.htaccess` file.

I'm not sure if this is something special about WAMP and whether it's out-of-the-box behavior.  I can't find any documentation on being able to control/change this behavior.